# Installer Error 1721 - Win 10 won't allow writing a file component, possibly permissions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, installation, permissions

Out of thousands of Windows 10 clients, ONE USER running Windows 10 Home Edition gets an error from our Installshield-created installer:

```
 Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. 
 A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.
 Contact your support personnel or package vendor. 
 Action spchapi.exe, location: C:\Users\TheUserName\..\spchapi.exe
```

spchapi.exe is the installer for a legacy (32-bit) speech api package, and one of the components we are installing.

The user is running the installer with admin privileges, and also logged into an admin user.

All I can think of is that somehow some directory doesn't have the right permissions -- but for several folders, when I look at the Properties, there ISN'T EVEN A SECURITY TAB!  Is this some Windows Home edition magic?  We must have thousands of Windows Home Edition users, and they have no problems.

Anyone have any theories?

Comment: Pretty certain it would fail -- installation MUST happen via an admin, because device drivers / daemons are installed in system folders.  But that's not the part that is failing.

Comment: I'm saying if he logs in as a normal user (but he only has ONE user, and it's the administrator) then the installer would fail for sure, because I THINK he needs to be logged in as admin.  But what were you thinking about how that could help?

Comment: @Biswapriyo - Sure, here's a temporary link to the installer:  https://we.tl/Y3waeW23nS